# How to test the performance of a java application?

Tags: java, performance, netbeans-6.9, evaluation

I've created a stand alone java desktop application using Netbeans. I want a way to test the performance of my application. I need some tool with the help of which my application can be evaluated. I heard about Software metrics, is this related to my context. Or is there any tool or plugin available in Netbeans through which I can test.

Comment: What kind of metrics are you trying to test, processor, memory, disk i/o, a combination, none of the above?

Comment: Yes, please define "performance" within your question.

Comment: Try printing the source code and feeding it to your dog. If your dog doesn’t eat it all it’s probably bad. :)

Comment: Actually i want to show that my application is trustworthy and dependable. For this i need some mechanism to measure the quality or performance of my application.

Comment: @Bombe I do understand, why you added this as an comment rather than as an answer where people could donwvote.

Comment: @dmcnelis i want to test all of which you have mentioned.

Comment: DerMike, then you realized the difference between a snarky comment and an answer. Congratulations, you have almost all prerequisites for a site like Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Netbeans Profiler:

> http://netbeans.org/features/java/profiler.html

Comment: Please can you tell me some link which tells how to use the Netbeans profiler. I am not understanding exactly where to put the profiling points.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has one of the best profilers going for Java apps, it runs well and provides as much detail as you want. Since you're using Netbeans I'd take advantage of it!

In terms of tutorials, there's one [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/nb-profiler-uncoveringleaks_pt1.html) about memory leaks and how to debug / discover them using the profiler. Once you get going with it the other features should come pretty easily.